# Is it possible to declare variable values using an array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php file that is called when a user clicks a link on a web page. It requires weekly manual editing of several variables. If I could define the variable values from an array it would be much easier to edit.

Currently the code is laid out thus:

```
   $event1Name = "Name of first event";
   $event1Date = "Date of first event";
   $event1Location = "Location of first event";
```

...and so on for each event.

Is it possible to assign variable names and values from an array?

```
<?php
$num=0;
$Name="Name";
$Date="Date";
$Address="Location";
$array = [
    ["Poker @ Bob's", mktime(0,0,0,4,17,2021), "1450 That Street"],
    ["Poker @ The Legion", mktime(0,0,0,4,23,2021), "104 This Street"],
    ["Poker @ Petey's House", mktime(0,0,0,4,24,2021), "1776 America's Avenue"],
    ["Poker @ The Shriner's Club", mktime(0,0,0,5,8,2021), "33 Over There Blvd."],
];
foreach ($array as [$loc1, $time1, $address1]) {
++$num;
$event.=$num.=$Name = $loc1;
$event.=$num.=$Date = $time1;
$event.=$num.=$Location = $address1;
}
?>
```

Comment: Use an associative array. There is no need to create *n* variables which you will only use once.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_arrays.htm

Comment: You need to manually edit a file weekly ? Are you looking for a database ?

Comment: I need to assign values to variables. Everything I read from these comments implies I echo the values to a page. I do not.

Where I beleive this fails is assigning the name of the variable. ie:

    $event.=$num.=$Name

Comment: I think [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) are what you're after.

Comment: _“Everything I read from these comments implies I echo the values to a page. I do not.”_ - well then what do you _actually_ need these exact variables for? Especially considering that what you posted as an answer now, does exactly that … echo each of those values.

Comment: Echoing the values in the solution was simply to demonstrate that the variables were in fact created by the code. Nothing more. The values in the array are only to create an example, and not actually in use.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

Many thanks to El_Vanja for pointing me in the right direction. I knew nothing of variable variables.

```
<?php
$num=0;
$Name="Name";
$Date="Date";
$Address="Location";
$array = [
    ["Poker @ Bob's", mktime(0,0,0,4,17,2021), "1450 That Street"],
    ["Poker @ The Legion", mktime(0,0,0,4,23,2021), "104 This Street"],
    ["Poker @ Petey's House", mktime(0,0,0,4,24,2021), "1776 America's Avenue"],
    ["Poker @ The Shriner's Club", mktime(0,0,0,5,8,2021), "33 Over There Blvd."],
];
foreach ($array as [$loc1, $time1, $address1]) {
++$num;
    $var = "event" . $num . $Date;
    $$var = $time1;
    $var = "event" . $num . $Name;
    $$var = $loc1;
    $var = "event" . $num . $Address;
    $$var = $address1;
}

echo $event1Name . " on " . date("F d, Y",$event1Date) . " at " . $event1Location . "<br>";
echo $event2Name . " on " . date("F d, Y",$event2Date) . " at " . $event2Location . "<br>";
echo $event3Name . " on " . date("F d, Y",$event3Date) . " at " . $event3Location . "<br>";
echo $event4Name . " on " . date("F d, Y",$event4Date) . " at " . $event4Location;
?>
```